# Nest intercepter is not working properly with async method

Tags: express, nestjs, token, interceptor

I want to store the ip address and hit count for a perticular api so i created this intercepter and this is only logging (Before...) console and moving on to the api feature without returning any error.
I tried hitting api without token and it is still hitting api fine.

```
import { Injectable, NestInterceptor, ExecutionContext, CallHandler, HttpStatus } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { tap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Model } from 'mongoose';
import { User } from '../entity/user-entity';
import { InjectModel } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { Request, Response } from 'express';


@Injectable()
export class ResponseInterceptor implements NestInterceptor {
    constructor(@InjectModel(User.name) private userModel: Model<User>) { }

    intercept(context: ExecutionContext, next: CallHandler): Observable<any> {
        console.log("Before...")
        const req = context.switchToHttp().getRequest();
        const res = context.switchToHttp().getResponse();

        return next.handle().pipe(
            tap(() => {
                const token = req.headers.authorization?.split(' ')[1];
                console.log("token", token);
                if (!token) {
                    res.status(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED).json({ message: 'Missing token' });
                    return;
                }

                this.processRequest(req, res, token);
            })
        );
    }

    private async processRequest(req: Request, res: Response, token: string): Promise<void> {
        const user = await this.userModel.findOne({ token }).exec();
        if (!user) {
            res.status(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED).json({ message: 'Invalid token' });
            return;
        }
        
        user.hitCount += 1;

        
        const ipAddress = req.ip;

        
        const responseStatus = res.statusCode;

        
        user.ipAndResponses.push({ ipAddress, response: responseStatus });

        try {
            await user.save();
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error saving user:', error);
        }

        req.user = user;
    }
}
```

how can i solve this isse?

Answer (score 0):

The code in the `tap` is ran **after** the execution of the controller that this interceptor is bound to. If you want to run it before it needs to be done before the `return next.handle()` call. You can make the `intercept` method `async` if you like, it just then returns a `Promise<Observable<any>>` which Nest still handles just fine

Comment: as you can see I want to store response status code in my database and if i write my code inside `tap` then it only store data on a success response and if i write the code before `tap` then it store both success and error as success response, how can i store both success and error status codes when someone hit my api

Comment: `tap` has an alternate form of `tap{ next: nextHandler, error: errorHandler })`, however, be aware that Nest **most likely** has not set a status at this point, and exception filters can still modify the status as well, so even if you **do** get a value, it's not guaranteed to be correct. My [OgmaInterceptor](https://github.com/jmcdo29/ogma/blob/main/packages/nestjs-module/src/interceptor/ogma.interceptor.ts) makes a pass at trying to properly log this value